# Recommendations for managing multiple instances of the same polymer element in a page?

Tags: polymer

I have a general question.  One of the major benefits of building a new polymer element is that it can be used like a native HTML element in a page.  So, depending on the element that you build, it's logical that you would be able to add multiple instances of that element in a page.

Say I build a simple task list polymer element that has multiple views.  A *simple view* that just lists the task names in a list and a *detailed view* that list the tasks and many other properties of the task in a list.

Then I add the element to my page multiple times.  Maybe I want one instance of the element to list tasks related to *Home* and another to list tasks related to *Work*.  But I want to send a link to someone with the *Home* task list opened in the *simple view* and the *Work* task list opened in *detailed view*.  Or maybe I want the Home task list opened in *edit mode* and the Work task list opened in *view mode*.

How would you build the element so that you can change attributes/settings to more then one of these elements on a page?

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of polymer is that you can change your component view by just adding / changing attributes to it.

Create custom tags and provide specific attributes depending on your requirement (HOME / WORK profile), and change your view accordingly.

Example:

> **Step 1**: Create task container

```
<polymer-element name="task-list" noscript>
  <template>
    <h3>Tasklist</h3>
    <core-menu id="tasks">
        <content></content>
    </core-menu>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

> **Step2**: Create task component

```
<polymer-element name="add-task" attributes="label detail">
  <template>
    <div id="task">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tick" on-click="{{lineThrough}}" /> {{label}}
        <div style="color:#999;margin: 5px 25px;">
            {{detail}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('add-task', {
      lineThrough: function() {
        this.$.task.style.textDecoration = this.$.tick.checked ? 'line-through': 'initial';
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And now using above components, you can create your basic task list:

```
<task-list>
  <add-task label="Learn Polymer" detail="http://www.polymer-project.org/"></add-task>
  <add-task label="Build something great" detail="create polymer element"></add-task>
</task-list>
```

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Now, To have control over changing task view (list / detailed / editable). Just add 2 attributes to `task-list` component. To control child view `add-task` from parent `task-list` element, you need to [publish properties](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#published-properties) of your child element.

### Your child component should be:

```
<polymer-element name="add-task" attributes="label detail">
  <template>
    <div id="task">
        <template if="{{isEditable}}">
            <input value="{{label}}" />
        </template>
        <template if="{{!isEditable}}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="tick" on-click="{{lineThrough}}" /> {{label}}
        </template>
        <template if="{{isDetailed}}">
          <div style="color:#999;margin: 5px 25px;">
              {{detail}}
          </div>
        </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('add-task', {
      publish: {
        isDetailed: false,
        isEditable: false
      },
      lineThrough: function() {
        this.$.task.style.textDecoration = this.$.tick.checked ? 'line-through': 'initial';
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

### Parent component with required attributes

```
<polymer-element name="task-list" attributes="editable detailed">
  <template>
    <h3>Tasklist</h3>
    <core-menu flex id="tasks">
        <content></content>
    </core-menu>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('task-list', {
      editable: false,
      detailed: false,
      domReady: function() {
        var items = this.$.tasks.items;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].isDetailed = this.detailed;
            items[i].isEditable = this.editable;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

That's it, now you can control your task view by specifying required attributes to your parent component.

```
<task-list detailed editable>
  <add-task label="Learn Polymer" detail="http://www.polymer-project.org/"></add-task>
  <add-task label="Build something great" detail="create polymer element"></add-task>
</task-list>
```

### Screenshots

#### With `detailed` and `editable` attributes

[image: With <code>detailed</code> and <code>editable</code> attributes]

#### Without `detailed` and `editable` attributes

[image: Without <code>detailed</code> and <code>editable</code> attributes]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  What you say makes perfect sense and I like how you designed your solution.  But your example only goes into having **one** task list on the page.  My specific question was how do you manage setting default values for attributes on two or more instances of the same polymer component on a page?  More specifically, how do I send a link to someone to my webpage that has two or more task lists on it.  Specifying that each task list be in a different state/mode?

Comment: For example, if my page had:
`<task-list id="WorkTasks" detailed editable>
  <add-task label="Learn Polymer" detail="http://www.polymer-project.org/"></add-task>
  <add-task label="Build something great" detail="create polymer element"></add-task>
</task-list>`

List 2:
`<task-list id="HomeTasks">
  <add-task label="Clean House" detail="Lots of stuff to clean"></add-task>
  <add-task label="Cook Dinner" detail="Steak... yummy!!!"></add-task>
</task-list>`

How do I create a url that I can send to someone to open the Home task list in edit mode but the Work task list in detailed view mode?

Comment: Do I add a url-encoded JSON object as a parameter in the link that specifies what modes to display each list in?

Thanks!!!

Comment: check out flatiron-director component of polymer https://github.com/PolymerLabs/flatiron-director - you can specific #hash type url and share it. Demo Implementation you can check here - http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html#one

Comment: Using flatiron-director - you can change view / settings depending on route object which you can bind with your component.